# Pulsate effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

any idea why the below code does not work? See http://jsfiddle.net/6RJNL/
Thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".banner5").effect("pulsate", {
        times: 5
    }, 2500).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't load the `jquery-ui.min.js` in your fiddle.

[**Check it now**](http://jsfiddle.net/6RJNL/1/)

Go on left in *External Resources* to load other JS libraries.

Anyway stackoverflow is not a *"jsFiddle how to use"*.

A better check from you would have solved your problem before posting :)